# Dynamic URL routes for Static site in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a static site, there is no way to add in re-writes via htaccess or similar which is how would normally approach this functionality.  We're running the site with Vue, on top of static .html templates eg

`\example\index.html`

So I can visit [www.mywebsite.com/example/](http://www.mywebsite.com/example/) and it'll load the page, and run Vue, when I want a subpage, based on this layout, I currently have to create

`\example\subpage\index.html`

Again this works great [www.mywebsite.com/example/subpage/](http://www.mywebsite.com/example/subpage/), but what I'm wanting is to pull data in via an API feed, and be able to have dynamic URLs

`\example\subpage\any-page-name-here`

The closest I've found is to use # so

`\example\subpage#any-page-name-here`

Which allows Vue to pick up the data after the # and query the API with that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, there's no work around for the limitations of the hosting, so I need a Vue/JS/HTML only soltion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot change the web server configuration, the only possibilities are the hashtag option or the query string e.g

```
example.com/site/?dynamic-data
```

The reason is the web server decides what to do with the request in the first instance, and without any configuration it will simply load a page if it exists or show a 404. This happens before your Vue app is invoked.

Comment: So there's no way with Vue, to at least catch the click and update the URL inline, even if a full page "refresh" would trigger a 404 which is captured by the server before Vue can get involved?

Comment: I would think that is possible yes, but of course a user could not directly visit the URL and as you say, it would trigger a 404 if the user refreshed. I wouldn't recommend that though - I'd go with the hashtag approach.